# How to populate Category in Post and Show in Option in Node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to populate the category in Post.
I'm making a CMS, where users can create/edit/delete posts and categories. I'm trying to implement a function that allows the user to choose created category while making the post. From the option.
Here is some important code.
**Post Module**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: "public",
    enum: ["public", "private"],
  },
  image: String,
  createdBy: {
    type: String,
  },
  category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
    require:true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

//! Exporting Module
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

**Category Module**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  }
});

//! Exporting Category Schema
module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
```

**Post Controller**

```
const Category = require('../model/Category');
const Post = require("../model/post");

// @ desc POST / Add New Post
exports.postNewPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cate = await Category.find();
    const post = await Post.create(req.body);
   
    req.flash("alert", {
      type: "success",
      message: "Book created successfully",
    });
    res.redirect("/posts");
  } catch (error) {
    req.flash("alert", {
      type: "danger",
      message: "Something is wrong..!",
    });
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**AddPost.ejs**

```
<form role="form" action="/posts/addpost" method="POST"
                               enctype="multipart/form-data">
// Here is other input fields like as title,description,status
// Here I want to populate category and allow user to choose
<div class="row">
                                                    <div class="input-field">
                                                        <label for="category">Choose Category</label>
                                                        <select name="category" id="category">
                                                            <% cate.forEach(cate=>{ %>
                                                                <option value="<%= cate.name %>">
                                                                    <%= cate.name %>
                                                                </option>
                                                                <% }) %>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
</form>
```

But it’s isn’t  working Please help me.
For reference Github repo Url : https://github.com/yajindragautam/Advance-CMS-Using-Ejs

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to populate `category` when you call the `find()` method, you have to call also the `populate()` method.

You can find how to use populate in the [official documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate). Pay attention at the version of mongoose you are using, because in latest releases the`populate()` method call has changed, if you have more than one filed to populate, you can find more details in [Migration guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate).

In your case I think you can only add `.populate('category)`.

```
const cate = await Category.find().populate('category);
```